# Flutter Web App Full screen on Mobile Browser

Tags: flutter, web, fullscreen

I've build my flutter Mobile Web app and released it to to the web. I do find that there is some default space at the top and the address bar at the bottom that stays there no matter which page I navigate to. How can I get these removed so that the User only views the App / Site in full screen.

I tried Media Query and the full screen options with no avail.